# How to send an ArrayList<String> to Another Activity and display there?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

How to send an ArrayList to Another Activity and display there ?
I Want to get data from another activity and send it to another activity and get there printed. I am only able to pass single string but not an array of strings

*Code On Java File,*

**Main Activity:**

```
EditText et1 , et2 , et3 , et4 ;
public final static String MESSAGE_KEY = "com.example.prabhav.myapplication.message";
ArrayList<String> ar , tr = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_full_on);
}

public void sm (View v)
{
    et1= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    String msg1 = et1.getText().toString();
    et2= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dob);
    String msg2 = et2.getText().toString();
    et3= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailinput);
    String msg3 = et3.getText().toString();
    et4= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.clgi);
    String msg4 = et4.getText().toString();
    ar.add(msg1);
    ar.add(msg2);
    ar.add(msg3);
    ar.add(msg4);
    tr=ar;
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,SecAct.class);
    intent.putExtra("myarray",tr);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

**Another Activity:**

```
Spinner s;
public final static String MESSAGE_KEY = "com.example.prabhav.myapplication.message";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent= getIntent();
    ArrayList<String> ls = (ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("myarray");
    ArrayAdapter<String> adptr=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,ls);
    s= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp);
    s.setAdapter(adptr);

    //  setContentView(R.layout.sec_lay);

}
```

Comment: what is the problem your facing with current code?

Comment: use intent.putStringArrayListExtra("myarray", tr);

Comment: The Application gets closed , after i click the button.

Comment: @Nag Its Getting Closed.

Answer (score 3):

Once try as follows

**MainActivity**

```
Intent i = new Intent(this,SecAct.class);
i.putStringArrayListExtra("myarray", tr);
startActivity(i);
```

**2nd Activity**

```
ArrayList<String> list=(ArrayList<String>)getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("myarray");
//use the list as you wish
```

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: When i used the above code, it says, cant resolve i. 
And if i just change the second activity code, the application gets stopped as earlier .

Comment: Its Still Not Working

Answer (score 0):

try sending the arrayList using **putParcelableArrayList** like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,SecAct.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putParcelableArrayList("myArray", (ArrayList<? extends android.os.Parcelable>) tr);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        startActivity(intent);
```

And you can get the arrayList in the second activity like this:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {
        tr= bundle.getParcelableArrayList("myArray");}
```

i hope this will help

Comment: Error:(45, 95) error: inconvertible types
required: ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>
found:    ArrayList<String>